# Prevent closure to from renaming object keys

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a `document['key']` that i am defining in elsewhere in my code. Basically an API key that is being set by client in html `<script></script>` tag like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  document.clientKey = 'a uuid unique to client';
})();
</script>
```

i called this key in my javascript file via `document['clientKey']` and it was working fine, until i passed it to closure, which renames it to `document.I`. Can I force closure to keep the string `'clientKey'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [Understanding the Restrictions Imposed by the Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations)

> Using string names to refer to object properties:
>
> The Compiler renames properties in Advanced mode, but it never renames strings.
>   If you need to refer to a property with a quoted string, always use a quoted string

```
var x = { 'unrenamed_property': 1 };
x['unrenamed_property'];  // This is OK.
if ( 'unrenamed_property' in x ) {};   // This is OK
```

Comment: yes, in my code, it is document['clientKey']. calling the property using the string :)

Comment: In your example code above - it is not quoted. You need to quote it to prevent renaming.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realized my mistake after i posted this.